# Sorting or reordering OrderedDictionary<String, ImagePost> = [:] on ASCollectionNode - swift not working

Tags: swift, ordereddictionary, asyncdisplaykit

Trying to sort OrderedDictionary - the format = 
var OrderedDictionary = [:], on a ASCollectionNode but not working. 
I tried using. but still no success. please I need your help.

```
self.OrderedDictionary.sort(by: { (f1, f2) -> Bool in
                return f1.value.posedDate?.compare(f2.value.posedDate!) == .orderedDescending

            })
```

Comment: Date conforms to Comparable protocol `sort{ $0.value.posedDate > $1.value.posedDate }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying , but I got this error when tried your answer............ "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'NSNumber?' operands'

Comment: You can compare its doubleValue properties

Comment: I also tried this ....     self.orderedPhotos.sort{ $0. value.posedDate?.intValue > $1.value.posedDate?.intValue }.     but it duplicates the same picture over and over again.